# MariaDB St_Within

Tags: within, mariadb

Recently I noticed that `ST_Within` stopped working properly on ***some*** features.
The geometry that breaks `st_within` has 1337 vertices (ESRI arc - many segments 1cm distance).
If I reduce the vertices number the `ST_Within` works again.
The MariaDB version that I am using is 10.3.29.
I do not know if there was an update that caused the above problem, but it was working perfectly a week ago.
Any ideas what is causing the problem?

The vertices and SQL are uploaded to this file as they too large/messy to add to this context

[Sql data and WKT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WR9wxFmaphyYHc5DugwGl7qfpLEuCm4U/view?usp=sharing)

```
----UPDATE-----
```

The spatial index is the one that causes the breaking. When I dropped the spatial index of the column the `ST_Within` started working again. Any ideas what causes the spatial index to ignore the geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.3.29 was released yesterday with the introduction of ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467). It's not supposed to have had an impact on any existing functionality, but perhaps its related. Either way, if it was working before, and is not now, you should report it as a bug with more details, and someone can investigate further.

Comment: Note that `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` seems to work on a pair of `Point`s only, all other combinations yield an "Internal error: st_distance_sphere" (MariaDB 10.5.13)